# Getting the values from a selected radio button and passing them to new activity

Tags: android, android-intent

### How to get the text of selected radio button(I have Customized)

I have a set of radio buttons in a group as below

- breakfast
- lunch
- dinner

Out of these only one will be selected Because they are radio button group

[image: img]

*How to get the text of selected radio button and pass them as intent to next activity*

**Any Ideas ?**

---

I know how to pass the intents to next activity by getting a value from `Edittext` but not able to do this for `radio button group` !

***What i have tried***
**this is how i did for getting the values from edit text** ::

```
EditText City;     
Search=(Button) findViewById(R.id.SEARCH_BUTTON_ID);
            Search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent searchIntent=new Intent(SearchPage.this,AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView.class);
                    searchIntent.putExtra("REST",City.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(searchIntent);
                }
            });
```

### How can i achieve this same for as i mentioned in radiobutton group !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this
**xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:gravity="center" >
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rdg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/breakFast"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:text="BreakFast"/>

            <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/lunch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:text="Lunch"/>

            <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/dinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:text="Dinner"/>

        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/SEARCH_BUTTON_ID"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Search"/>
</LinearLayout>

**Activity**
 private RadioGroup rdg;
    private RadioButton breakFast;
    private RadioButton lunch;
    private RadioButton dinner;
    private String selectedType="";
    private Button Search;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rdg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdg);
        breakFast = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.breakFast);
        lunch = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.lunch);
        dinner = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.dinner);
        Search=(Button) findViewById(R.id.SEARCH_BUTTON_ID);
        breakFast.setSelected(true);
        rdg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                if(i==R.id.breakFast){
                    selectedType = breakFast.getText().toString();
                }else if(i==R.id.lunch){
                    selectedType = lunch.getText().toString();
                }else{
                    selectedType = dinner.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        });


        Search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent searchIntent=new Intent(SearchPage.this,AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView.class);
                searchIntent.putExtra("REST",selectedType);
                startActivity(searchIntent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hey its almost perfect but ..... Final piece i need is i got the text from radio button as u suggested .... but i need to pass it as Extra through Search button of my code not directly launching new activity from radio group ... is it possible to make some changes

Answer (score 1):

Each group of radio buttons should be in a group, I assume you did this already in your XML file.

Assuming that, then you get the ID of the checked radio button by doing:

```
int id = ((RadioGroup)findViewById( R.id.radio_group )).getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

You can do that anywhere in an Activity, or if you're using a Fragment, then you just need to put a getView() in it:

```
int id = ((RadioGroup)getView().findViewById( R.id.radio_group )).getCheckedRadioButtonId();
So I would change your onClick:

public void onClick(View v) {
    // Create a new Intent
    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), FeedbackResults.class);

    choice = (String)county.getSelectedItem();
    int id = ((RadioGroup)findViewById( R.id.radio_group )).getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    atmos = getAtmos( id );
    ...
}

private int getAtmos( int id ) {
    switch( id ) {
        case R.id.arad1:
            atmos = "1";
            break;
        case R.id.arad2:
            atmos = "2";
            break;
        case R.id.arad3:
            atmos = "3";
             break;
        case R.id.arad4:
            atmos = "4";
        break;
        case R.id.arad5:
            atmos = "5";
            break;
    }

    return atmos;
}
```